# NPM packages installation error - it's not only about vite it's same problem during installing any packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

```
node:9720) [DEP0170] DeprecationWarning: The URL http://proxy.example.com:port is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:5040) [DEP0170] DeprecationWarning: The URL http://proxy.example.com:port is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL
npm ERR! Invalid URL
```

Comment: Follow the instruction in your error message. Find the place with running node with --trace-deprecation. Replace invalid url from error message with correct one.